# How to select (-) icons while editing a tabel, in Iphone UIAutomation

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios, ios-ui-automation

Hi i am learning UI-Automation on I phone, can any one tell me what reference should be used to select (-) or (+) buttons while editing a table.

Answer (score 0):

set the editing property of UITableView to true..

```
 tableView.editing=YES;
```

Answer (score 0):

For Deleting, this works for me:

```
    tableView.cells()[cellName].switches()[0].setValue(true);
    tableView.cells()[cellName].buttons()[0].tap();
```

So I'd assume that for "+" you'd just need to tap button at index 0:

```
    tableView.cells()[cellName].buttons()[0].tap();
```

Now that you can use Instruments to record your actions that is probably the easiest way to get the correct syntax that will work for you.